# Expression evaluation

Tags: hold

I have got the following solution to an equation:

```
{{xc -> (2.54648*10^-6 (-555.653 Sqrt[-3306.94 + Exp] Sqrt[Exp] - 
      9.00829 Exp))/Exp}, 
{xc -> (2.54648*10^-6 (555.653 Sqrt[-3306.94 + Exp] Sqrt[Exp] - 
      9.00829 Exp))/Exp}}
```

How I can put *Mathematica* to evaluate the numerical value for this expressions of `xc`, because it seems that is not giving more than this for the moment?

Also what it means the Exp at the denominator and `Sqrt[Exp]`? It doesn't have any sense for me.

Comment: What is the equation you have solved? Probably there is a typo in the equation giving the Exp, with no arguments, in the solution.

Comment: `Exp` by itself will evaluate to `Exp`. Seems like you got some syntax / definition problem upstream.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Marius.What do you mean by typo?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error

Answer (score 2):

I think you wrote `Exp` in your equation where you should have written `E`. By substituting `E` for `Exp` in your answer, you would get

```
sol /. Exp -> E
```

> ```
> {{xc -> -0.0000229394 - 0.0493323 I}, {xc -> -0.0000229394 + 0.0493323 I}}
> ```

Another possibility is that you wrote `Exp(...)` where you should have written `Exp[...]`, in which case a simple substitution as shown above won't work. You will have to correct and resolve your equation.

Comment: @m_goldberg Why these kind of questions are not deleted? IMO clearly syntax error related questions should be deleted to avoid cluttering search results.

Comment: @ercegovac. I don't have an answer. If you feel strongly about it, ask your question on [Mathematica Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com)